# How can I find order of the permutation in a symmetric group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

I would like to get orders of permutations in a symmetric group $S_n$. What is the easiest way to find them?

I know, how to find them by enumerating the permutations of $S_n$ group, then I add the same permutation several times until I get neutral element. As the n gets higher, it is much harder.

In a group $S_7$ is the highest order 12 in permutation (1234)(567). That is, what I found here [Element structure of symmetric group:S7](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Element_structure_of_symmetric_group:S7).

> Is there some formula that I can use to determine, that order in permutation(1234)(567) is 12?

Comment: Just take the lcm of the cycle-lengths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Since $(1\ \ 2\ \ 3\ \ 4)$ and $(5\ \ 6\ \ 7)$ commute, the order of $(1\ \ 2\ \ 3\ \ 4)(5\ \ 6\ \ 7)$ is the least common multiple of the orders of $(1\ \ 2\ \ 3\ \ 4)$ and $(5\ \ 6\ \ 7)$. That is why it is $12(=\operatorname{lcm}(4,3))$.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand the problem :)

Comment: Why does this follow?

Comment: @LukeCollins I did not understand your question.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I'm not sure why $xy=yx\Rightarrow |xy|=\operatorname{lcm}(|x|,|y|)$.

Comment: @LukeCollins You will find a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2818199/446262).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks!